# How come `gcc` did not emit any `fence` instuction? Ain't memory barriers needed here?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, atomic, memory-model

I am playing with `stdatomic.h`, the C11 memory model(s) & the latest stable `gcc` that compiles for a modern x86-64 Intel CPU.

The following C11 code:

```
void lock(struct spinlock_t *sl) {
  while (atomic_exchange_explicit(&__sl.taken, 1, memory_order_acquire))
    while (atomic_load_explicit(&__sl.taken, memory_order_relaxed))
      __asm volatile("pause" ::: "memory");
}
```

with the `-O3` flag emits the following assembler:

```
0000000000001370 <lock>:
    1370:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1374:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
    1379:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
    1380:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
    1383:   48 87 05 8e 2c 00 00    xchg   %rax,0x2c8e(%rip)        # 4018 <__sl>
    138a:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
    138d:   74 11                   je     13a0 <lock+0x30>
    138f:   90                      nop
    1390:   48 8b 05 81 2c 00 00    mov    0x2c81(%rip),%rax        # 4018 <__sl>
    1397:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
    139a:   74 e4                   je     1380 <lock+0x10>
    139c:   f3 90                   pause  
    139e:   eb f0                   jmp    1390 <lock+0x20>
    13a0:   c3                      ret
```

It is perfectly expected to see the `pause` there. However, I am having hard times explaining to myself why no `fence` instructions were emitted? Where are the memory barriers? How does this assembly guarantee sequential consistency after all?

Comment: You used explicit memory orders weaker than seq_cst, but `xchg mem,reg` and plain `mov` load are both as strong as you'd get with `seq_cst` because of x86 memory ordering rules.

Comment: Note that taking a lock only needs to be an `acquire` operation on the lock object; that's how the C source is written.  But as I said, the x86 asm is also a valid implementation of source that used `seq_cst`.

Comment: The x86 fence instructions have no effect on the ordering of ordinary memory reads and writes. They only  affect ordering of instructions or memory types  that are specifically designated as weakly ordered.